# How to use ansible win_package module to install firefox with an ini file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the ansible win_package to install firefox like so:

```
- name: win_package install firefox
  win_package:
    path: http://<path to exe>
    product_id: 'Mozilla Firefox'
    state: present
```

I need to install firefox with an ini configuration file.  I know the win_package takes arguments, but it's not clear to me how I can pass a file to the installer.  Where do I put the ini file and how do I pass it to the exe?

Comment: You haven't specified any steps that you have already tried w.r.t that ini file. But I would expect `{{ ansible_env["TEMP"] }}` would be a reasonable place to put the ini file, as for "how do I pass it to the exe," how do you do it by hand right now?

Comment: I can successfully do it using win_command but that's not idempotent. I could certainly run a check to see if it is installed before hand to get around that, but there are multiple applications I'm going to need to install down the road, so was hoping to use the win_package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by downloading the ini file to the remote server and then running the following task:

```
- name: win_package install firefox
  win_package:
     path: http://<path to exe>
     product_id: 'Mozilla Firefox'
     state: present
     arguments: '-ms /INI=C:\Temp\firefox\mInstall.ini'
```